# Saved my texture paint, and when I loaded it again.. It looked like this?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

[image]

Not sure how to fix it. Originally, everything was colored a deep red. Then after saving it, some of the red turned white and the red lightened. I did texture paint within Blender. I do not have Substance Painter. I only have Photoshop and GIMP.

Comment: what is your display mode? and also your color management settings?

Comment: Do you mind if I add a link? https://imgur.com/a/9VvGXVe                                                          As for display mode, do you mean my viewport? I'm under the viewport shading tab. (Sorry, I'm a bit new-ish to Blender.)

Comment: could you please pack your images (File > External Data >Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F74_XVH2xWsCBupRxR6HtmW747Hhbx8x/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                                    hopefully it works! Thank you.

Comment: google says: file not found.

Comment: I tried fixing it after you said it was over 1GB. I believe its cause my low poly is now high poly, lol. Ill probably do retopology again or use un-subdivide. Heres the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wK3prQnjcd6eLxlyoNppOnQsF34EYaOF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Wow, it must be really high-poly. I recommend to save always multiple versions of your work. If you select a filename in the save window and press the '+' key then Blender automatically adds a number to it or increases the number. Just keep an eye on the disk space. In the save window there is also a compress option.

Comment: Hmm, the download always stops around 83%-87%. That's annoying. I'll try to download it from another computer.

Comment: You know what. It's alright! I'll figure out how to fix the makeup or just cave in and use another application or it. It is high poly. I still have the original high poly saved with the 'low poly' one as well. Not as many vertices/faces as the original one but still pretty high. It's my first character, so I've made a lot of errors.